# Navigation Drawer & Fragments

Tags: android-fragment, drawerlayout, android

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать переключение фрагментов по нажатию на определенные пункты listview в navigation drawer.

Нажимаем в listview на первый пункт - отображается fragment1, нажимаем на второй пункт - отображается fragment2.

Насколько я понимаю, переключать фрагменты нужно в функции selectItem, но где их создавать и как правильно переключать?

Спасибо!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String[] mDrawerListNames = {"Fragment_1", "Fragment_2"};

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDrawerListNames);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mDrawerListNames[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }
}
```

**Fragment2.java**

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я делаю так:

```
public static void commitFragment(Fragment fragment, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE); //добавляет fade
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

R.id.fragmentLayout - это id лэйаута в activity_main, в который встанет фрагмент

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

    ...

    switch(position){
      case 0:
      commitFragment(new Fragment1(), getFragmentManager());
      break;

      case 1:
      commitFragment(new Fragment2(), getFragmentManager());
      break;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! У меня был похожий вариант реализации, но мне он показался неверным, ведь при каждом клике мы создаем новый экземпляр фрагмента.

Не будет ли правильнее, если мы в onCreate MainActivity создадим фрагменты, а в selectItem будет переключать уже созданные ранее фрагменты?

Comment: Почитайте [тут][1] коменты, умные люди имеют мнение

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/337488/java-повторное-использование-объектов

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд наиболее верным будет создание интерфейса описывающего по какому параметру происходит переключение между фрагментами ─ position в listview, _id в базе и тд.. реализация этого интерфейса в Activity,

```
extends ActionBarActivity implements Navigate {
```

Статистический метод для запуска фрагмента, (просто пример не привязан к конкретному случаю)

```
 public static MyFragment newInstance(long id) {
        Bundle arg = new Bundle();
        arg.putLong(ID, id);
        MyFragment fragment = new JobListFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arg);
        return fragment;
    }
```

При создании фрагмента в onAttach проверить что Activity реализует интерфейс

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            mNavigate = (Navigate) activity;

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement Navigate.");
        }
    }
```

И вызывать методы интерфейса из фрагмента, это актуально не только для Navigation Drawer

Answer (score 0):

[Android Custom Navigation Drawer](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 0):

В предыдущем проекте я вот такую реализацию использовал.

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view,
                                    int position,
                                    long id) {

                String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Категории);

                mTitle = rivers[position];

                Fragment f;
                if (position == 0) {

                    f = new MyCompanyFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);

                    ft.commit();

                }
                if (position == 1) {

                    f = new MyEmployeeFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);

                    ft.commit();
                }

                if (position == 2) {
                    f = new CalendarFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                }
                if (position == 3) {
                    f = new SettingsFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);

                    ft.commit();
                }
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

            }
        });
    }
```